# iOS 8 / Xcode 6 "Embed Framework" Build Phase Destinations

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I've been working with custom iOS Frameworks for a while now using both [pre-Apple-supported method](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) as well as the new iOS 8 / Xcode 6 built-in Framework methods and just recently noticed something interesting in the Xcode interface I can't seem to find any documentation about. Was wondering if anyone had any pointers as to why and when one would use that.

So when you build the new-model framework, we need to not only add it as a reference to your app project and include it in your target's `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section but also add it to the `Embedded Binaries` "General" section of your target.

That makes it so that Xcode automatically adds a new "Build Phase" called `Embed Frameworks` which has the same list of frameworks added to the previous "General" section, but here it lets you pick a "Destination" which by default is obviously the `Frameworks` directory in your bundle. See image below with other Destination options.

[image: xcode embed framework build phase]

I saw some [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) around building Frameworks for the purpose of sharing code between an app and an extension where they say people should not use "SharedFrameworks" as a destination, otherwise it would render the app ineligible for App Store submission (so I'm guessing you could still use it for enterprise distribution), but the main question remains, what do those destinations entail and what kind of features come with embedding the framework in a different destination such as "Java Resources"?

Perhaps the interface is the same for both OSX and iOS apps and maybe some of those only apply for Mac apps, but since I couldn't find any documentation at all about those destinations thought I'd throw it out there to see if anyone has ever had any exposure to them.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode is just an IDE. It can be used to code on any language, e.g. Java. However, in such case you will need to write the commands that launch a compiler by yourself as "Custom Scripts". Often the result of the compilation and packaging is a **bundle** that follows a well known structure. "Embed Frameworks" just takes an artifact and puts into a result bundle into a known subdirectory. There options pre-define the subdirectories you might choose to put your artefacts in.

For more information about bundles you can [read this documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH100-SW1) (search for Java)